# LARAVEL : SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column please fix this

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Hello im getting the following error while saving the data Here's the error prompt:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'description' in 'field list' (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `postings` (`productname`, `description`, `image`, `price`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (edwa, eww, 1682654259.webp, 250, 2023-04-28 03:57:39, 2023-04-28 03:57:39))

laravel keeps saying : A column was not found and also saying "You might have forgotten to run your database migrations.

but I don't know what's the matter of my code

> Here's my web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "web" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class,'index'])->name('home');

Route::get('/post_page', [AdminController::class,'post_page']);
Route::post('/add_post', [AdminController::class,'add_post']);

/*Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('dashboard');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('dashboard');*/

Route::resource('reservation_models','App\Http\Controllers\ReservationController');

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');
});

require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

Controller:**AdminController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use \App\Models\posting;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function post_page()
    {
        return view('admin.post_page');
    }

    //for request data
    public function add_post(Request $request)
    {
        $post=new posting;

        $post->productname = $request->productname;
        $post->description = $request->description;


        /////////////responsible for keeping image in public folder
        $image = $request->image;
        $imagename=time().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $request->image->move('images',$imagename);

    /////////////storing image in database
        $post->image = $imagename;

        $post->price = $request->price;

        $post->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

**Model:posting**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class posting extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

post_page.blade.php

```
<style>
.div_center
{
text-align:center;
padding:20px;

}
</style>
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot name="header">
        <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
            {{ __('Admin Post Page') }}
        </h2>
    </x-slot>
    <body class="post_title">
       <div style="text-align:center;"> <b>Add post</b></div>
            <div>
                <form action="{{url('add_post')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    @csrf
                        <div class="div_center">
                            <label> Product Name:</label>

                            <input type="text" name="productname"></input>
                        </div>

                        <div class="div_center">
                            <label> Description:</label>

                            <input type="text" name="description"></input>
                        </div>

                        <div class="div_center">
                            <label> Price:</label>

                            <input type="text" name="price"></input>
                        </div>

                        <div class="div_center">
                            <label> Image:</label>

                            <input type="file" name="image"></input>
                        </div>

                        <div class="div_center">

                            <input type="submit" style="" class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="image"></input>
                        </div>
                </form>
            </div>
    </body>
    

</x-app-layout>
```

I already stared every necessary line of code but, I still don't get my error

Comment: Run `php artisan migrate:fresh` this command will drop all tables and re-migrate your migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can just go to database and check spelling of column in DataTable.